# Trying to use replace function (python)

Tags: python-3.8

I am learning python ,i.e., version 3.8
While trying to replace a string substring using replace() function.

```
str = "Python"
str.replace("th", "t")
print(str)
```

Output:
Python

Expected Output:
Pyton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **replace()** returns a copy of the string with all occurrences of
>   substring old replaced by new

You need to assign to a variable to store the copy

```
str = "Python"
replaced_str= str.replace("th", "t")
print(replaced_str)
```

[image]